# Face detection in OpenCv other than Haar cascade?

Tags: c, opencv

I am trying to implement face detection in OpenCv. But using Haar Cascades it becomes very slow and cannot be a real time. I heard about SURF.

Can anyone help me to implement  fast face detection using SURF or other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for usage example of SURF, take a look at `samples/c/find_obj.cpp`. However, I doubt that it will work faster than Haar Cascade classifier. Cascade classifier uses quite simple features - just rectangular regions of an image, and SURF is much more complicated.

You can also try other algorithms starting from very simple but inefficient [Eigenfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface) and ending with complicated but full-featured [Active Appearance Models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_appearance_model) (see list of implementations on Wiki's page). Though it will require a lot programming and is still unlikely to beat Cascade classifier results. So, I would suggest reconsidering other parts of the system. For example, I believe it is possible to detect faces in background thread and show it with little delay. Also if you want to use it for head/face tracking, you can run detector only for some region, close to the previous location of face.